# Stream pdf to s3 while it creates

Tags: python, file, pdf, backend, streaming

I'm use python lib PyPDF to make pdf from images and then i load it to s3.
Now it makes in memory, so sometimes generated pdf goes out of memory.
I want streaming it to s3 while pdf generates.
And i dont found ready solutions this task, may be some one knows?

As i represent:

- Make header with count of pages -> sent to streaming response
- Make page -> send
- Another page -> send
  ...
- Make tail -> send
- profit

Is it real to make with python libs or it's only way to make my own lib?

I tried to use private method of PyPDF like _write_header but it hard to use for my task

Comment: Is there a reason you can't or don't want to use the local hard drive to generate it, then upload it at the end? You didn't actually say why it has to be streamed, just that you want it to.

Comment: Did you consider using `Python S3 connectors`, which can be used to save the streaming data from `PyPDF` to a specific file in an S3 store?

Comment: There is difficult to use hard drive because lot of libs use stream file like objects (~BytesIO)